# How can I cast a string in a format 'dd.mm.aaaa' to a data type in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table with some date columns as string in the format 'dd.mm.aaaa'. How can I cast them to a data type in Hive?

Comment: Are you thinking to cast as `date` type?

Comment: Yes! for a date format such as 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`dd.MM.aaaa`** is not hive compatible **`date`** type format, so we need to use `from_unixtime` and `unix_timestamp` functions to change the format!

**`Example:`**

```
hive> select date( --cast to date type
          from_unixtime( --change the format to yyyy-MM-dd
               unix_timestamp('09.12.2019','dd.mm.yyyy'), --parse input data
            'yyyy-MM-dd')
          );
```

**`Result:`**

```
2019-01-09
```